# Linux. Инкрементальный бэкап GUEST системы Windows в KVM на LVM

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server, резервное-копирование, lvm

Есть у меня сервер, на нем есть KVM. Стоит в KVM Windows Server 2012R2, диск подключен как lvm раздел.
Сделать целый бэкап диска не проблема, делаем снапшот а дальше любыми средствами снимаем архив. А вот как сделать инкрементальный бэкап, ума не приложу.
Или все таки проще делать из самой винды бэкап в host систему? Но такой вариант не очень нравится.

Да и вообще интересен инкрементальный бэкап не только раздела на котором стоит винда, но и другие дистрибутивы, тот-же Linux. Acronis же умеет это как-то делать. Хотя там вроде как обычный dd используется.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/283008/454489 , но быстрее будет работать, вероятно, если воспользоваться каким-нибудь высокоуровневым инструментом. типа [bacula](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacula).

Comment: ZFS для линуха ещё не сделали?

Comment: При чем тут ZFS? Если надо бэкапить lvm том на котором стоит Windows.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/IncrementalBackup

Наслаждайся. Но это сложно. Есть еще lvm thin provisioning. Но он жутко анстейбл. Есть бтрфс чтобы типа на нем хранить qcow2 или raw. но он не так быстр как лвм. Есть зфс но он ест память и не стандартен.

В общем, это боль.

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае можно делать хоть через dd+xdelta3, но конечно лучше использовать встроенный в Windows механизм резервного копирования на подключенный выделенный раздел.

Если же стоит твердая задача делать именно на хостовой системе, то я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону снэпшотов ZFS и их передачи по сети на сервер бэкапов средствами самой ZFS.